# Checkstyle 6.0 on hudson seem to produce a wrong html result

Tags: tags, hudson, meta, checkstyle

I'm receiving the following error message when I try to run checkstyle 6 with hudson.

[CHECKSTYLE] Parsing of file /var/lib/hudson/jobs/Checkstyle/workspace/dist/report/checkstyle_report.html failed due to an exception:

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 55; columnNumber: 3; The element type "META" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

Is there anything I can do to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error, has nothing to do with checkstyle. The Hudson job should only parse an xml to html file and not an html file.